# How to include raw html file into razor view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have some code and would like to do some additional modularisation so I would like to have my component Calendar inside its own html (it's not a complete html but one whose outer tags are `<div>`)

I've tried to do things like

```
            @RenderSection("~/Views/Home/_TSCalendar.html")
```

But he seems not to like it.
Also, I want to route to my outer cshtml file and not this **_TSCalendar.html** to which I'm pointing.

How do I insert a raw html file into my .cshtml view?

Comment: Surely not a duplicate as this refers to razor, the linked one refers to the old aspx engine.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Why don't you use partialview?

Anyway what you're trying can be achieved by this -

```
@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Views/Home/_TSCalendar.html")))
```

You can pass any html as a string to @Html.Raw

### Update

Just create a new partial view in your Shared folder (if you want to use it across the application), and add the following code in your Views wherever you want to use calendar component. You do not need to explicitly navigate to your partial to access it.

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_TSCalendar")
```

You can even pass values like selectedDate and use that value in your _TSCalendar partial.

Comment: I have to make a calendar component and I really dont feel like writing a lot of html since I prefer jade syntax much more. I was hoping to write  the whole thing in jade and then just compile it and the resulting html to my existing view. I do not want to change navigation.

Comment: What you want to achieve is the ideal place where one would use partials. Creating a partial is like creating a template/component, where you can have static html or pass a model just like you'd pass to a View.

Comment: Just updated my answer to better explain it.

Comment: I'm not using MVC (or ASP.NET) but I'm using Razor. When I tried to add @Html it doesn't compile for me. Is there any using I need to add to the page? I want to include some common header and common footer, e.g. file with just <head>

Comment: in ef core you can inject @inject 
```
@Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment hostingEng
@Html.Raw(System.IO.File.ReadAllText($"{hostingEnv.WebRootPath}/js/form-permission.html")))
```

Comment: I guess you mean aspnet core?

Answer (score 2):

As CoOl has said - if using MVC I highly recommend using PartialViews - in your case you may just have a simple piece of HTML but if you start using them now you'll realise how powerful it is to be able to call in HTML to your page, and even pass a model/subset of a model into the newly generated view.

If you go to add a new View in VS, you will see a checkbox for 'Create as partial' or something along those lines. 
You can literally just add HTML within  tags as you've said above and just call

```
 @Html.Partial("_PageToLoad")
```

Comment: Yeah but do I have to nagivate to the _PageToLoad or can I route to the parent view which only includes this partial inside?

Comment: Imagine a PartialView like a function - you can write code once and then call it wherever you like and inject the view into your existing code.

Your Partial could literally just be a <table> setup with a certain amount of rows for example with correct css styling, and then whenever you want a table, just call the @Html.Partial("_MyTable").

Obviously you can be a lot more creative than that ;)

To answer your question - you don't navigate to a Partial, it is injected into the page you want it in.